# Bootstrap 3 menu not collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a a website using bootstrap and I'm not able to get the menu to close on mobile when I click the toggle, it does open fine just not close. I've tried a few solutions that i've found on here but none have changed anything with the toggle. The website does have all the components needed (jquery, all the bootstrap files) and there are no errors on the console. Here's the HTML Code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <!--<div class="topLogo"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a></div>-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav">
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">How It Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Apply</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The two snippets i've tried that aren't working are -

```js
$(document).on('click',function(){
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

and

```js
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
  if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
   $(this).collapse('hide');
  }
 });
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/GV598DvYgw there must be some other css or js that's conflicting.

Comment: Yupp, I just checked as well and it's working fine, even without your JS code. https://jsfiddle.net/q1Ls5ywf/

Comment: Do you see any error in the browsers Console?

Comment: nope there's nothing there, I'm just removing things from a copy of the code right now one by one and running it to see what's breaking it